# Como empaquetar correctamente un jar con un archivo json

Tags: java, json, maven

tengo un proyecto que quiero distribuirlo en otras computadoras ,estoy empaquetandolo en un fat jar usando el plugin de *maven shade* .
Este proyecto usa un archivo de *json* que tiene unas credenciales de la api de google , al correr el proyecto en mi IDE funciona correctamente pero al querer correr el proyecto desde el ejecutable jar  y concretamente intentando correrlo desde el cmd:

```
java -jar miproyecto.jar
```

Me arroja el siguiente error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 
  at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:890)
        at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:125)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:156)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:139)
```

Tengo entendido que esto ocurre porque el método que lee el archivo json devuelve un valor null, pero como mencione anteriormente el proyecto corre perfectamente desde el IDE (Netbeans 15).No he encontrado forma alguna de poder arreglar este error.

¿Hay alguna forma concreta de empaquetar el proyecto en un jar para que también lea el archivo json?

Este es la configuración de mi plugin:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.projecto.projecto</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Adicional: tanto el archivo json y el metodo que lee este archivo son de otro proyecto que agregue como dependencia de mi proyecto actual, por lo que no se si eso tambien influya.

Comment: Descomprime el jar y revisa si el json se encuentra ahí.